# Windows 10 update: change/choose edition?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

Is it possible to choose which edition of Windows 10 I want?

In Windows Update, Microsoft "suggests" me to install *Windows 10-Home Edition*, can I choose another edition? Can I change it after the installation?

I ask becase according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions):

> In Windows 10 Home, **it is not possible to make changes to how the
>   Windows Update works - it is automatic, and one cannot choose which
>   updates will be downloaded and installed**.

And this really bugs me (bold is mine).

I am currently using Windows 8.1 64 bits.

Comment: If you're using a non-Pro edition, you can only upgrade by purchasing an upgraded licence, afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image answers your question. If your current version gives you home you must purchase your upgrade to get Pro.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The Wikipedia article is about Windows update after you're running Windows 10, not upgrading from win7/8 to win10. When you do the upgrade, it will upgrade you to the home edition. If you want a different edition you need to buy that edition of win10 from Microsoft and use the provided installer. What that article says is that on windows 10,security fixes are automatic, you can't turn them off (although you can delay them, and it schedules them for times you don't usually use your computer).